# How do I get user deleted from Django database when I delete from Auth0 users and vice versa?

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, auth0, django-users

I am using Auth0 with my Django App for users login/logout authentication. I want a way that when I delete any User from Auth0, the same user account should be deleted from Django Database, likewise if I delete any user account from Django, the attached user from Auth0 should be deleted as well.

How will I achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

For deletion from Auth0 to go to your backend:
you can use [log streams](https://auth0.com/docs/customize/log-streams); listen to the delete event and fire a deletion in your DB

For deletion from your backend to go to Auth0:
upon deletion in your DB, call auth0 [management-Api](https://auth0.github.io/node-auth0/ManagementClient.html#deleteUser) to make the deletion in Auth0

Comment: I am new to Auth0 and an average Django developer. Can you explain in detail what you said above in your answer?

Comment: which part can i help with? are you stuck in a particular step; there is sufficient documentation around these

Comment: I have implemented the login & logout process using the Quickstart guide of Auth0 for Django. I have SQLIte DB in Django & Auth0 default DB inside it. When I register a user using Auth0 interface, it get's registered in Django SQLite DB as well. But when I remove user from Auth0 interface, the user does not get removed from Django DB. Similarly, when I remove user from Django Admin Interface, it does not get removed from Auth0 default DB. How do I achieve this functionality?

You told me about log streams & API. I am new and I have not used these before. Can you explain step by step?

Comment: on log streams, help [here](https://auth0.com/docs/customize/log-streams/custom-log-streams); don't see python as an option for [calling managementAPI](https://auth0.com/opensource)... open question [here](https://community.auth0.com/t/how-do-i-call-auth0-management-api-from-my-django-app/88759)

Comment: Thanks for the help in log streams. BTW, that open-question you mentioned is opened by me, but have not received any response from any expert yet :/